# How to configure two broadband connection on the network so that if one goes down other can automatically start catering to Internet requests

Tags: internet, dhcp, wifi-configuration, broadband, bridge-router

Our earlier setup was
12 PCs connected via a switch. These PCs can connect to eachother via LAN. Broadband connection was via ADSL modem cum router plugged into the switch so that all PCs get internet connection too.
Default gateway was 192.168.1.1.

As this broadband connection has been giving issues since 2-3 months we thought of getting a different broadband connection from some other vendor. But this was on Cable Broadband technology hence we purchased a DSL router (Modem was provided by service provider). The default gateway for this connection is 192.168.0.1

Now both the broadband are working fine on wifi.

What is want is primary broadband should be the new connection so all machines can take advantage of newer connection. Also if at all this broadband goes down, the other connection automatically takes over. One should not require to change any setting on all PCs. I have heard that this can be achieved by setting up DHCP server but i have not received any concrete way/steps to achieve this.

Kalpak

Comment: Look for dual-WAN gateways. They have failover capability that you ask for. You can also turn a Linux box into a similar gateway - the machine just needs three network adapters (two for WAN, the other will go to your LAN). They all, also, can be configured so that no changes are needed for your LAN at all. All the failover stuff is done internally. Although we don't provide product recommendations we use DrayTek dual-WAN router but I've also used an OpenSource Linux distro called Endian Firewall (community version).